# The code needs to shift through 2000 rows to see if any cell in the range has “Y” and if it does to write “Y” in the first column

Tags: excel, vba

The code needs to shift through 2000 rows to see if any cell in the range has  "Y" and if it does to write "Y" in the first column

This is the code that I have done that works, but very repetitive for 2000 rows:

```
Range("BD5").Select

Set rng = Range("BD5:CI5")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "Y" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
  Next cell
End If

'add loop to last cell 2000 times or 1250 times'

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Set rng = Range("BD6:CI6")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "Y" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
  Next cell
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Set rng = Range("BD7:CI7")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "Y" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
  Next cell
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Set rng = Range("BD8:CI8")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "Y" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
  Next cell
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Set rng = Range("BD9:CI9")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "Y" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
  Next cell
...
```

This is the code I tried to do with looping but did not work because I cannot figure out how to loop the range to look at only one row at a time and then move to the next

```
Range("BC5").Select

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("BD5:CI5")

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "Y" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
  Next cell
End If

For I = 1 To 100
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
  Set Range = rng.Offset(1, 0) 'need to edit this so that the range will go through all rows in the document'

  If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
      If cell.Value = "Y" Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
    Next cell
  End If
Next I
```

Comment: Please post your code as text not as a screenshot, cheers.

Comment: When you paste your code here AS TEXT highlight it and then click the little `{}` button (or indent each line with four spaces) to have it formatted as code. Please don't post pictures of code. And definitely don't take a picture of your monitor displaying your code and post that.

Comment: Moving the active cell is rather slow. You can directly access cells in a worksheet via the `Cells` collection (e.g. `ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value`).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
Sub test()
Dim myArray As Variant, i As Long, myRange As Range
With Sheets("Sheet2") 'name of your sheet
Set myRange = .Range("BD5:CI2000")
    With Application
    myArray = myRange
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    If InStr(1, Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(.Index(myArray, i, 0)))), "Y", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then myArray(i, 1) = "Y"
    Next i
    myRange.Resize(, 1) = .Index(myArray, 0, 1)
End With
End With
```